# Disable all Sundays in jQuery UI Calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I want to disable Sundays in jQuery UI calendar.

From docs I came to know about this:--

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 4,beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

This will disable Saturdays and Sundays both. But I want to diasble only Sunday. Is there any default option for this.

**Bad way to solve it**

beforeShowDay take true or false as params for every day. So write a function which returns true or false based upon each day.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

try this

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
    }
});
```

Comment: Or to add this event as an option to an earlier initiated datepicker instance:

    <!-- language: lang-js -->
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [(day != 0), ''];
    });

Comment: Bhanu Prakash and Imeurs, both the solutions not worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can disable Saturday and Sunday, In jQuery UI datepicker.

https://codepen.io/VijayDhanvai/pen/ExjdGPb

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 6),  ''];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this code 
it is working for me

```
$("#date").datepicker({
filter: function(date, view) {
if (date.getDay() === 0 && view === 'day') {
  return false; // Disable all Sundays, but still leave months/years, whose first day is a Sunday, enabled.
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

compared to the best answer, here's how to add options to the datepicker besides disabling Sundays :

```
$('#datepicker_fin').datepicker(
            {
                beforeShowDay: function(date) 
                {
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    return [(day != 0), ''];
                },
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeYear: true,
                maxDate: null
            });
```