# I want to disable all Sunday

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, magento-1.9.1

```
function () {
    // initialize date picker with correct date format
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField: 'delivery_date',
        ifFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        align: 'Bl',
        button: 'delivery_date',

        singleClick: true,
        disableFunc : function(date) {
            var today = new Date();
            today.setDate(today.getDate() + 4);
            date = date < today;
            return (date);
        }         
    });
}
```

The above code for disable dates of after five days of current data.
I want to disable all Sundays also

How can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this:

```
disableFunc : function(date) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 4);
    return date < today || date.getDay() == 0;
}
```

Here you make a double check, so to disable all dates more than 4 days ahead and all those that come on sunday.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

> The value returned by getDay() is an integer corresponding to the day
>   of the week: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

Comment: in the default code :today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
when i modified this -1 to 4
I am not able to select the date

Comment: I just copied you code for that, and then added the logic to exclude sundays, just adjust the number to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
    }
});
```

Reference: [Disable all Sundays in jQuery UI Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376987/disable-all-sundays-in-jquery-ui-calendar)