# block the day in every month in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I having a text box that had Text mode as date.I want to block Sunday of all month/year. suggest me some Idea.

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtfromdate" runat="server" Enabled="True" OnTextChanged="From_TextChanged" TextMode="Date" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: It's better to get a jquery date picker and disable SUNDAY..

Comment: you should use jquery datepicker and should see this as already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4377047/3748701

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable all Sundays in jQuery UI Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376987/disable-all-sundays-in-jquery-ui-calendar)

Comment: @RavintherM download datepick here  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as having client-side checking using JQuery, you should have server-side checking using e.g. C# in case this is bypassed. You could add a `CustomValidator` control, on the `ServerValidate` event get the `Value` string property of the `ServerValidateEventArgs`.  Convert to a `DateTime` using `DateTime.Parse` or such like, then if `yourDateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday` set the `IsValid` property of `ServerValidateEventArgs` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop beginning from first day of year to last day of year and for every day of year you can fetch `dayofweek` for every day. after that if `dayofweek` is equal to SUNDAY you can save it's date(month and day of month) in database. after executing of for loop you can fetch all dates in this table. and so.