# how to set range in calendar for 1 week in Django

Tags: django

I want to set range Monday to Saturday in the calendar in Django where user can select the date between this date and on Sunday user can not change the date

```
def tech_form(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
   form = TechForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
      start_date = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
      end_date = datetime.date(2020, 3, 31)
      Tech.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
      form=form.save(commit=False)
      form.save()
      messages.success(request,"Form Submited succesfully")
      return redirect('tech')
  else:
      form = TechForm()
  return render(request, 'hellogymapp/forms/tech_form.html', {'form': form})
```

please explain

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly. Right now one can not make much sense out of this.

Comment: okay now i did it.

Comment: I want a calendar where user can only select Date between Monday to Saturday.

Comment: @JeffVipul do you want calendar on frontend ?

Comment: @c.grey I want a calendar where user can select the date between Monday to Saturday

Comment: @JeffVipul but where do you want this selection

Comment: Actually I have created superuser(Admin) inside it has a calendar

Comment: use https://gijgo.com/datepicker and disable sunday

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376987/disable-all-sundays-in-jquery-ui-calendar       let me know if it is helpful .